# Calcular días laborales en Postgres 10.1

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito calcular los días laborales (sin incluir sábados y domingos) de una serie de datos bajo ciertas condiciones.

Un muestra de la tabla (sin todas las columnas) es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En postgres 9.3 tenía algo así:

```
SELECT 
    employee,
    (SELECT COUNT(days) 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 

                 CASE 
                        WHEN flag = 'A'    THEN generate_series(date1 , date2 , '1 day') 
                        WHEN flag = 'B'    THEN generate_series(date2 , date1 , '1 day') 
                 END AS days

    ) wd
    WHERE EXTRACT('dow' from days) NOT IN (0,6)) as "Working Days"
    -- Otras columnas no agrupadas
FROM table
```

Con esta solución obtenía la columna "Actual Result" que no es del todo correcta pero se aceptó temporalmente. Sin embargo hace poco se actualizó la versión del servidor a 10.1 y el **case** ya no es válido en el **select**

Cómo puedo obtener el dato presente en la columna "Expected Result"?

Saludos

Comment: Hmm. Me acabo de dar cuenta que en realidad tienes 2 preguntas en una. 1) Quieres evitar el nuevo error con PostgreSQL 10.1, pero 2) quieres corregir el resultado erróneo que obtenías también en la versión 9, ¿Correcto?

Comment: Hola sstan. Exacto. Aunque el dato negativo todavía no es tan crítico, es una mejora a realizar.

Comment: ¿Hay garantía que `date1` siempre es mas antiguo que `date2`?

Comment: Y aprovecho para dejar otras preguntas: ¿cujales son los flags posibles? ¿Solo `A` y `B`? ¿Y para qué sirven exactamente? ¿Es la idea simplemente que si `flag = 'B'` entonces la cuenta de días debería ser negativa?

Comment: No hay certeza sobre date1>date2; hasta ahora he 'negociado' con el usuario esto, pero me indica que no importa por ahora que el resultado final sea 0. Lo mismo ocurre con el dato negativo, es una petición que se tiene, y que en un par de semanas puede ser necesario para los análisis que ellos realizan. Aún se evalúa esto.

Comment: Entonces no me voy a romper el coco tratando de resolver tu segundo problema. Para proponerte algo que de verdad funcione, necesitaría entender mejor la lógica deseada, y para qué sirven los flags exactamente, como pregunté mas arriba. Por lo menos ya te dejé una respuesta para resolver el problema específico a PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: Si sstan, así está bien. Si el usuario no tiene muy claro que necesita, menos yo. Es algo de dialogar con él y ver que tan necesario es. Mil gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, parece que decidieron prohibir el que una expresión `CASE` pueda devolver un *set* de resultados, lo que me parece una buena idea. Puedes encontrar más información en cuanto a esto en [esto hilo](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/000001d2d5de%24d8d66170%248a832450%24%40pcorp.us#000001d2d5de$d8d66170$8a832450$@pcorp.us).

Una solución que minimiza los cambios necesarios a tu consulta es de sacar el `generate_series` fuera de la expresión `CASE`, y mas bien, usar el `CASE` para determinar los parámetros a la llamada `generate_series` de forma individual.

O sea, en vez de:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN flag = 'A'
            THEN generate_series(date1 , date2 , '1 day') 
       WHEN flag = 'B'
            THEN generate_series(date2 , date1 , '1 day')
       END AS days
```

...lo modificas a:

```
SELECT generate_series(
           CASE WHEN flag = 'A' THEN date1 WHEN flag = 'B' THEN date2 END,
           CASE WHEN flag = 'A' THEN date2 WHEN flag = 'B' THEN date1 END,
           '1 day') AS days
```